# Is it possible to add text into SWF file online by ASP.NET or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash, edit

I have a site that contains some videos that made by graphic designer , he also edit them now and then and add videos. I want to add text to the video that after X seconds at the bottom of the video that will show some text. For example: "Hosted by XXX". I cannot ask this from the designer because the text changes once a month and he will charge me for that work every time.
This videos are in swf (flash) format. I need to do it online - while the page loaded or even asynchronously. My site it wrote in asp.net so this must be done(if it can) by asp.net or javascript.

I have zero knowledge in flash but I have now problem to learn if this thing possible..

Can you say if it is possible? And if so give the concept by it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html and javascript (preferably using the JQuery and JQuery UI javascript libraries)

Write a javascript function to show and position your html element.  You will need some way of determining the coordinates dynamically.

Have this function fire on the click of a video object e.g

`onclick='myJavascriptFunction(videoID)'`.

If you need to delay it you can do that in the javascript function.

Comment: For now thats sound like the best thing I could do. Can I get the video current status? like stop/pause/play and what is the time of the video every second?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in html (driven by asp if you will)?

Or am I missing something?

Or you could acces a webserver to load in text, or you could add it in the flashvars, or ...

Comment: How to do it by html? I dont want to put the text under the video, but on-top of it. Flashvars just pass variables to the swf, isnt it? And what about webserver?

Answer (score 0):

First you need the source code for the file.
Just a SWF will not work and I will not promote de-compiling someone elses work.
Next in the HTML you set up [flashvars](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=flashvars%20example%20as3&aq=0&aqi=g1g-v2g-j5g-b1&aql=&oq=flashvars%20example%20) to be passed to your flash app the flash var will contain your text for the label.
Finally You create a TextField in the flash app and assign it the [flashvar](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html)

Comment: Without the source code you are stealing that persons work unless you contracted for it.